# Issue with Using WebRTC getUserMedia with UWP WebView

Tags: javascript, uwp, win-universal-app, webrtc, winjs

I've created a basic UWP application with a `WebView`. I'm navigating to this URL: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/ to test the use of `getUserMedia()`.

The error I get is:

> getUserMedia error: NotFoundError

I have also add Capabilities Webcam capability to enable the Camera device for your app. but no luck.

Does anyone know if this should be possible, and if I'm therefore doing something wrong? Anyone using `getUserMedia` within a UWP `WebView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need allow [`PermissionRequest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView#handling-special-cases-for-webview-content) in `PermissionRequested` event handler.

> In addition to the app handling the PermissionRequested event, the user will have to approve standard system dialogs for apps requesting location or media capabilities in order for these features to be enabled

```
MyWebView.PermissionRequested += MyWebView_PermissionRequested;

private void MyWebView_PermissionRequested(WebView sender, WebViewPermissionRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    if (args.PermissionRequest.PermissionType == WebViewPermissionType.Media)
    {
        args.PermissionRequest.Allow();
    }
}
```

**Update**
For WinJS app, you could refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview#mswebviewpermissionrequested).

```
document.getElementById('live-preview').addEventListener("MSWebViewPermissionRequested", permissionRequestedEventArgs => {
    const permissionRequest = permissionRequestedEventArgs.permissionRequest;
    switch (permissionRequest.type) {
        case "geolocation":
        case "media":
            permissionRequest.allow();
            break;
        case "pointerlock":
        case "webnotifications":
        case "screen":
        case "immersiveview":
        case "unlimitedIndexedDBQuota":
        default:
            permissionRequest.deny();
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Nico but I have used WinJS and you have given me C# code. Could you please give me solution in WinJs code. Below is the sample code which I have used and getting error    getUserMedia error: NotFoundError                                                                                                           
  <x-ms-webview id="live-preview" style="display: block; width: 100%; height: 450px; overflow: hidden;" src="https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/gum/"></x-ms-webview>